# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement OleDBCOmmand

Tags: c#, .net, oledb, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

I have an issue when trying to insert Rows from Datatable into an Excel sheet. I keep getting syntax error but when i insert the sql string into mssql server there is no issue verifying the sql statement.

this is my code:

```
public void InsertData(DataTable kpiData)
{
    string folderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\KPIReports\";
    string fileName = @"\Return_Report - " + DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() + ".xlsx";
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath);
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        File.Delete(file);
    }

    File.Copy(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\ReportTemp.xlsx", folderPath + fileName);
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection connection;
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
    string sql = null;
    connection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + folderPath + fileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;ReadOnly=False;HDR=YES;\"");
    connection.Open();
    myCommand.Connection = connection;

    foreach (DataRow row in kpiData.Rows)
    {
        string weight = row[11].ToString().Replace(',', '.');
        sql = "Insert into [Data$] (WeekNr, AccountNumber, Barcode, Barcode2, PickupDate, DeliveryCustID, DeliveryAlias, PickupCustID, PickupAlias, DeliveryAttentionName, Coli, Weight, Note, DeliveryType, " +
                    "Name, Street, HouseNo, Postal, City, DanxCode, Receiver, PODTime, OnTime, [Service]) Values('" + row[0].ToString() + "','" + row[1].ToString() + "','" + row[2].ToString() + "','" + row[3].ToString() + "','" + row[4].ToString() + "','"
                    + row[5].ToString() + "','" + row[6].ToString() + "','" + row[7].ToString() + "','" + row[8].ToString() + "','" + row[9].ToString() + "','" + row[10].ToString() + "','" + weight + "','" + row[12].ToString() + "','" + row[13].ToString() + "','"
                    + row[14].ToString() + "','" + row[15].ToString() + "','" + row[16].ToString() + "','" + row[17].ToString() + "','" + row[18].ToString() + "','" + row[19].ToString() + "','" + row[20].ToString() + "','" + row[21].ToString() + "','" + row[22].ToString() + "','" + row[23].ToString() + "')";

        myCommand.CommandText = sql;
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    myCommand.Dispose();
    connection.Close();
    releaseObject(myCommand);
    releaseObject(connection);
}
```

and this is the sql string:

```
Insert into [Data$] (WeekNr, AccountNumber, Barcode, Barcode2, PickupDate, DeliveryCustID, DeliveryAlias, PickupCustID, PickupAlias, DeliveryAttentionName, Coli, Weight, Note, DeliveryType, Name, Street, HouseNo, Postal, City, DanxCode, Receiver, PODTime, OnTime, [Service]) Values('20','44730629311','12626707007','0681739685','10-05-2014 15:22:13','xxxxx','xxxx','xxxxx','Asker','','1','0.2','','N','xxx','xxxx','111','0665','xxx','xxx','xxxx','13-05-2014 07:00:00','OT','Reverse')
```

I cant seem to find the problem. I hope someone cant help me..

thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using an Excel connection string, which means you are trying to execute a T-SQL statement on an Excel spreadsheet. The syntaxes are different so a statement that works with SQL Server or MySQL will probably not work with Excel.
In any case, it's far easier to use SSIS to export an Excel file than do this in code

Comment: The error is most likely being generated because you're passing **all** values as strings... Try inserting just one column and see if you still get an error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue.

The problem was that i didnt have the Note column in brackets. Because Note is a reserved word then it has to have brackets around it like so: [Note]